# .HTACCESS - remove part of the url

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using in my cms with a pre-defined htaccess, as the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I want to update the url in order to remove 2 "sub directories":

from `/en/top/solutions/?id=1` to `/solutions/?id=1`
from `/en/top/about/?othervar=1` to `/about/?othervar=1`

this one of the things i did so far:

```
RewriteRule ^en/top/ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I could not get it to work.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `$1` means "use the first capture part of the original url". In order to capture a part of the original URL, you need to use a parenthesis to capture it in. Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/en/top/(.*) /$1 [QSA]
```

This means "take anything that starts with `/en/top/`, then capture what follows and put that into the variable $1. Rewrite to just the $1 variable and append the original query string.